# How to hide half area of container in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have fortune wheel in circle and its getting full screen I want to show wheel only half
and put buttons like check image for better understand

[image]

[image]

here is code

```
body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: FortuneWheel(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                animateFirst: false,
                selected: selected.stream,
                items: [
                  FortuneItem(
                      child: Text('0'),
                      style: FortuneItemStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15))),
                  FortuneItem(
                      child: Text('32'),
                      style: FortuneItemStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      )),
                  FortuneItem(child: Text('15')),
                  FortuneItem(child: Text('19')),
                  FortuneItem(child: Text('4')),
                  FortuneItem(child: Text('21')),
                  FortuneItem(child: Text('2')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Stack and Positioned

```
return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                ), // Put FortuneWheel here instead of Container
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2, // Height of the device divided by 2, so the red Container would take half of the screen.
                color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).